# Place two objects at THE SAME spot in css

Tags: html, css

Let's assume I have 2 objects, *em* and a *button*

```
 <button class="navigateButton" wicket:id="rw">Test1</button> 
 <em class="logoutButton"><a wicket:id="rw2">Test</a></em>
```

Is there any way to place two of those objects at exactly same spot without using position:fixed? In code I handle which one should be shown, since they do different functions. I want to show it at one specific spot, regardless which one is hidden. There are never 2 of those displayed at the same time.

Comment: Did you try position:absolute?

Comment: Another alternative could be put an ID on a div and edit the inner HTML of the div and put either button in that you want to show?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put them both into a container `<div style="position:relative">` and give them

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
```

Comment: But won't this get ugly on different resolutions/browsers? Is there no option to put it in same line as I have it now without setting coordinates manually? As I said I want to avoid using position:fixed.

EDIT: Oh, all I have to do is just avoid setting top and left :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to click button and anchor at the same time with one click. You can use javascript for this purpose. Showing the 2 different objects at the same spot seems not good. Hide the em and use the below code.

```
$(".navigateButton").on("click",function(){
  $(".logoutButton a").click();
});
```

Comment: like I said, there is no situation where both of them are displayed, since I hide one of them in page code via Wicket(depending on situation)